# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8999999999999995"

Tags: java

I have a problem while I run my Program. The problem is on line 460  where i parse the string into int. Here is the code

```
       try {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT water_time, price\nFROM `watering` \nWHERE water_date BETWEEN ? AND ?");
            double pricesum = 0;
            double timesum = 0;
            ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(sDate.getTime()));
            ps.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(eDate.getTime()));
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                double time = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("water_time"));
                double price = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("price"));
                pricesum = pricesum + price;
                timesum = timesum + time;
            }
            String totalprice = String.valueOf(pricesum);
            String totaltime = String.valueOf(timesum);
            String[] totaltime2 = totaltime.split("\\.");
            int[] intArr = new int[2];
            intArr[0] = Integer.parseInt(totaltime2[0]);
     (line 460)       intArr[1] = Integer.parseInt(totaltime2[1]);
            double price_hour = intArr[0] * 5;
            double price_min = (intArr[1] * 5) / 60.0D;
            double price = (price_hour + price_min);
            jLabel8.setText((totalprice + " €"));
            jLabel7.setText((totaltime + " Ώρες"));
            jLabel12.setText((price+ " €"));
```

Problem

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8999999999999995"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at MainForm.jButton13ActionPerformed(MainForm.java:460)
at MainForm.access$000(MainForm.java:19)
at MainForm$1.actionPerformed(MainForm.java:135)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
```

Can you understand what is the problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That number doesn't fit in an `int`, use `long` instead: https://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/java/language/java-data.html

More information in the [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)) (emphasis mine):

> An exception of type NumberFormatException is thrown if any of the
>   following situations occurs:
>
> 1. The first argument is null or is a string of length zero.
> 2. The radix is
>      either smaller than Character.MIN_RADIX or larger than
>      Character.MAX_RADIX.
> 3. Any character of the string is not a digit of the
>      specified radix, except that the first character may be a minus sign
>      '-' ('\u002D') or plus sign '+' ('\u002B') provided that the string is
>      longer than length 1.
> 4. **The value represented by the string is not a value of type int.**

Comment: Do you know how to change code to make it work with long? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @AlexandrerPa `long[] longArr = new long[2]; longArr[0] = Long.parseLong(totaltime2[0]);`

Comment: @AlexandrerPa `Long.parseLong`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

If long is to small, use

```
BigInteger value = new BigInteger("8999999999999995",10);
```

You can calculate math functions with value and return it finally as int, long, byte[] or string in base 2,10,16 ...